Proving a disjunction without left nor right in Coq
A beginner's question again.
I'm in the current proof:
Lemma implication_over_conjunction_disjunction (P Q R : Prop) :
  ((P /\ Q) -> R) -> ((P -> R) \/ (Q -> R)).
Proof.
  intros.
  ???

which gives:
Goal 1

P, Q, R : Prop
H : P /\ Q -> R
(1 / 1)
(P -> R) \/ (Q -> R)

The problem is that neither left nor right suit, as they make false the goal to prove.
How can I progress?

This is not valid intuitionistically, so you'll have to use a classical axiom like excluded middle.

OK but excluded_middle is a definition in Coq.Logic.ClassicalFacts. How to use it?

The statement you are trying to prove is true classically but not intuitionistically, so proving it needs some classical law, either as an explicit assumption to the theorem or as an axiom.
Here is some commented code that shows both approaches, as well as what 'tauto' can do:
Definition DNE := forall P : Prop, ~ ~ P -> P.

(** By (intuitionistic) tauto
    with an explicit assumption. *)
Lemma imp_dist (P Q R : Prop) : DNE ->
  (P /\ Q -> R) -> (P -> R) \/ (Q -> R).
Proof.
  (*  This is guaranteed to work
      because applying DNE to
      a goal is equivalent to
      double-negation translation. *)
  intros dne; apply dne; tauto.
Qed.

Definition LEM := forall P : Prop, P \/ ~ P.

(** By "hand" (not fully filled in)
    with an explicit assumption. *)
Lemma imp_dist' (P Q R : Prop) : LEM ->
  (P /\ Q -> R) -> (P -> R) \/ (Q -> R).
Proof.
  intros lem.
  (*  Again guaranteed to work,
      this is by cases classically. *)
  destruct (lem P) as [HP|HP];
  destruct (lem Q) as [HQ|HQ].
  all: (* fill in or just: *) tauto.
Qed.

From Coq Require Import Classical.

(** By *classical* tauto
    using available axioms. *)
Lemma imp_dist'' (P Q R : Prop) :
  (P /\ Q -> R) -> (P -> R) \/ (Q -> R).
Proof.
  (*  Works because Classical changes
     the behaviour of [tauto]! *)
  tauto.
Qed.

(** By "hand" (not fully filled in)
    using available axioms. *)
Lemma imp_dist''' (P Q R : Prop) :
  (P /\ Q -> R) -> (P -> R) \/ (Q -> R).
Proof.
  (*  Again guaranteed to work,
      this is by cases classically. *)
  destruct (classic P) as [HP|HP];
  destruct (classic Q) as [HQ|HQ].
  all: (* fill in or just: *) tauto.
Qed.

My personal advice would be: use assumptions if most of your development is intuitionistic, so the classical theorems will stand out as such.  Otherwise, if it is mostly a classical theory, axioms might be just fine.

Couldn't be better. Thanks
